# How to convert PDF to DOCX or URL to DOCX with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx

I'm trying to research on `URL to DOCx` or `PDF to DOCx` conversation in NodeJS but didn't get any proper solution.

I reached out `PhantomJS` but It convert `URL to PDF` Is that any idea, Phantom can convert into DOCX?

Please give your suggestion regarding `docx` conversation.

**NOTE:** **HTML content to Docx does not require Because I've MAP and other charts available on HTML page so URL needed.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very few free, open source utilities that can convert HTML to DOCX and even fewer that can do it well, so asking specifically about Node.js is quite specific.  If you're comfortable shelling out a simple command, you can convert a URL to DOCX using [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/installing.html).  I recommend testing this utility locally without Node first.

```
pandoc -f html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656219 -o 48656219.docx
```

**Disclaimer:** Pandoc is a markup converter, not a full blown HTML renderer.  This means you will not have a full browser... e.g. You will lose formatting and there will generally be rendering problems for many common HTML and CSS techniques.  Here's a rendering of this page using `pandoc`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfUhw.png

If it works, you're in luck because there's an `npm` package for pandoc available.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pandoc

```
var pandoc = require('node-pandoc');
var src, args, callback;

src = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656219';
args = ['-f','html', '-o','48656219.docx'];

// Set your callback function 
callback = function (err, result) {

  if (err) {
    console.error('Oh Nos: ',err);
  }

  // For output to files, the 'result' will be a boolean 'true'. 
  // Otherwise, the converted value will be returned. 
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};

// Call pandoc 
pandoc(src, args, callback);
```

Comment: Found Issues : 
`Oh Nos:  Error: pandoc: 48656219.docx: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
    at Socket.onStdErrData (/home/gunjanpatel/workspace/risk_assessment/server/node_modules/node-pandoc/index.js:33:14)`

Comment: DONE, You missed `-o` in code so, I updated it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The update system on this website appears to be flawed for small edits.  I've corrected it, thanks!